# Exercício de SQL

Tags: sql

Boa tarde pessoal estou fazendo o seguinte exercício mas estou em dúvida se o fiz certo ou não, poderiam dar uma olhada?

Escreva as consultas SQL de acordo com o esquema de banco de dados presente abaixo.

a.  Selecione o ano, semestre e o nome dos cursos ensinados por [João Setubal].

b.  Selecione o RA e os nomes dos alunos do professor [Jacques Wainer] que assistiram ao curso [Evolutionary Algorithms] no semestre [1] entre os anos [2008] e [2010].

```
Student - (ra, student_name, admission_year, birth_date)

Course - (id, professor_name, course_name, year, semester)

Disciplina - (id, course:id, student:ra, grade_a, grade_b)


a. SELECT year semester course_name FROM Course WHERE professor_name = “João Setubal”

b. SELECT t1.ra, t1.student_name 
FROM Student t1 
INNER JOIN Disciplina t3 ON (t1.ra = t3.student:ra)
INNER JOIN Course t2 ON (t2.id = t3.course:id)
WHERE t2.professor_name = “Jacques Wainer” 
AND t2.course_name = “Evolutionary Algorithms” 
AND t2.semester = 1
AND t2.year BETWEEN 2008 AND 2010
```

Comment: Olá, o melhor jeito de saber se está certo é criar as tabelas, polular com dados que atendam e que não atendam à sua pesquisa e rodar seus selects. Boa sorte PS: Aparentenente está correto

Comment: Você pode usar o [SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/) para testar o sql.